# CAS Exception - Directory key is no longer valid. Quitting watcher service

Tags: cas

I am currently using CAS 5.2.3 and running our application in a Docker container. It runs fine locally without any issues but when I push the Docker image to the cloud in AWS as a Cloud Formation Stack, it throws the following error

`2019-01-28 19:13:31,339 WARN [org.apereo.cas.services.ServiceRegistryConfigWatcher] - <Directory key is no longer valid. Quitting watcher service>
Exception in thread "org.apereo.cas.services.JsonServiceRegistryDao" java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.checkOpen(AbstractWatchService.java:80)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.checkKey(AbstractWatchService.java:92)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take(AbstractWatchService.java:119)
at org.apereo.cas.services.ServiceRegistryConfigWatcher.run(ServiceRegistryConfigWatcher.java:72)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

I am not sure what is causing this. Please let me know if you need any further details.

Answer (score 0):

I search online and someone else also have your problem

Ref: https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!topic/cas-user/L0XUII6FazI

And judging from they response, the problem was a right issue with `Access Right`. Maybe this is also your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same. I gave it all the permissions (read, write, executable) but it still won't start. Thank you for looking though.